# Simple bash commands fails, cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, node.js, bash

I try to execute some simple bash in node bu get an error: 
`/usr/bin/file: /usr/bin/file: cannot execute binary file`

```
'use strict';

var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var process = spawn('bash', ['file']);
process.stdout.on('data', function(data){
    console.log(data.toString());
});
process.stderr.on('data', function(data){
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

I even gave the script chmod+x and i run it with node script.js

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like when you're spawning the child process, you're actually trying to run the "file" command, not a shell script, so bash is barking at you.

It would be equivalent to typing this on the command line: "bash file".

You'll want to write a shell script and pass that as the parameter to the bash process.

So, write a script called "do_something.sh" and then run your code with ['do_something.sh'] as the parameter to bash rather than ['file']:

```
var process = spawn('bash', ['do_something.sh']);
```

Comment: And make sure you've done chmod +x on do_something.sh, of course and that it's in your path.